# text file: how to remove line break if line does not start with number? (in emacs or sed)

Tags: emacs, sed, elisp

I have a **text file (data base output)** with too many line breaks, so **I have to remove some of those line breaks** (but not all of them).

I managed to do it by hand, but there are too many lines (thousands), so an automated solution would be helpful.

The aim is that in the end I have only lines in the text file which start with a number, all other lines shall be appended to the previous line (the last which started with a number)

What the code should do:

- go to each line
- if it DOES NOT start with a number [0-9] then go to the beginning of this line `(C-a)` and remove the linebreak *before* it (like hitting `backspace`)
  (the lines with numbers do not have leading spaces!)
- then go to the next line and do the same

this should be quite easy, but I don't know hot to do it.

A solution for Emacs would be helpful, but basically anything I can do within CYGWIN would also be very helpful.

Comment: Don't those directions join the wrong lines together? Isn't your goal to join all lines that *don't* start with a number to the line before them? Essentially remove the newline from each newline-non-number pair? (Do the lines have leading spaces?)

Comment: sorry, you're absolutely correct! I was too quick and edited my question. There are no leading spaces in the lines which start with numbers, and you are correct that only those which do NOT start with a number shall be appended to the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the goal is to remove all newlines that are not immediately followed by a number. One way with sed:

```
sed -i ':a $!{N; ba}; s/\n\+/\n/g; s/\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' filename
```

This reads the whole line into the pattern space, replaces all sequences of multiple newlines with just one, and then removes all newlines that aren't followed by a number.

**Addendum:** Ah, Cygwin. Caveat: The code, as it is, assumes UNIX line endings.  To make it work on a file with Windows line endings<sup>1</sup>, which may be important for you, use

```
sed -i ':a $!{ N; ba; }; s/\(\r\n\)\+/\r\n/g; s/\r\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' filename
```

This does the same thing with `\r\n` instead of `\n`. For a file with mixed line endings, use

```
sed -i ':a $!{ N; ba; }; s/\(\r\?\n\)\+/\n/g; s/\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/g' filename
```

(or use `dos2unix`/`unix2dos` before processing the file.)

<sup>1</sup> When the file is opened from a UNIX path or pipes are involved and the moon is gibbous, depending on the Cygwin settings. The handling of line endings in Cygwin is [convoluted and confusing](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html), and in general it is not a bad approach to just convert the file to UNIX line endings before processing it with Cygwin tools, then convert it back afterwards.

Comment: thanks a lot, also for the extended versions, but none of them seems to work. The number of lines (at least what I get with `wc -l filename.txt`) is still the same and the problematic areas are still there. :-(

Comment: If you want the file changed in place, give sed the `-i` option. Otherwise the processed output is printed to stdout (which you could redirect to another file or pipe somewhere). EDIT: I put `-i` into the answer.

Comment: thank you soo much and sorry for my ignorance, it worked perfectly, I just assumed it would directly change the file. With ` YOUR-SED-CODE filename.txt >> filename2.txt` it worked like a charm. :-))

Comment: Yeah...that's the sort of thing most of us are confused about once, and then once we know it, we forget it was once confusing. :P